# How to embed mediaplayer in webview -- android

Tags: android, html

I am embedding mediaplayer in webview using HTML5.

```
<p>
<img alt="" src="image7_jpg.jpg" style="height:262px; width:350px" />
test video<object width="160" height="144"><param name="autoplay" value="false">
<embed src="videoSample.3gp" width="160" height="144" autoplay="false" 
controller="false">  </embed></p>
```

The above is my `html5`, but when i load, mediaplayer was not get embed.

I got some suggestion from Google, it says,we need to include`<audio/video>` tag for to embed the multimedia file in `html5` for android.

I must to include the `audio/video` tag or the above html itself can work.

Please help me out. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

use video tag to play for [html5](http://html5media.info/) in android

```
<video id="video-example" width="256" height="177" poster="image7_jpg.jpg">
<source src="videoSample.3gp" type="video/3gp"></source>
This browser does not support HTML5
</video>
```

Comment: does video tag can play both audio and video format? but why the embed not working for android. i tried to load in several devices, but none will support.

Comment: did you enabled javascript in the webview settings

Comment: No, i dint enable javaScript for webview. incase if i enable the javascrit, will my webview can embed the mediaplayer.

Answer (score 0):

you should Add `webChromeClient` to webview and override `onShowCustomView(View view,CustomViewCallback callback)`.